# In Sinatra Can I Use Variables in a Route & View?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, haml

So I'm learning to use Sinatra (the very basics) and I understand the following basic code:

```
get '/derp' do
    haml :derp
end
```

I quickly got to thinking: if I have a dozen pages, do I have to write a get/do statement for each url, as above? There must be a way to use variables to do something like this:

```
get '/$var' do
    haml :$var
end
```

where `$var` is anything I type in. Basically if I type `/foo` in the address bar I want Sinatra to look for a view called `foo.haml` and use it, or else show a 404. Same for `/bar`, `/derp`, etcetera.

Is that possible? Am I misunderstanding some fundamental aspect of how this is supposed to work - should I ignore this question while I keep learning and come back to it later?

It seems like a really basic simple thing that would make lives easier, I can't imagine people are declaring each page manually...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this:

```
get '/:allroutes' do
  haml param[:allroutes].to_sym
end
```

Which will show the haml template for whatever :allroutes is. For example, if you hit `localhost/test` it will show the template under `test` and so on. Much more simpler version for this is by using the *match all* route provided by sinatra:

```
get '/*/test' do
  # The * value can be accessed by using params[:splat]
  # assuming you accessed the address localhost/foo/test, the values would be
  # params[:splat]  # => ['foo']
  haml params[:splat][0].to_sym # This displays the splat.haml template.
end

get '/*/test/*/notest' do
  # assuming you accessed the address localhost/foo/test/bar/notest
  # params[:splat]  # => ['foo', 'bar']
  haml params[:splat][0].to_sym # etc etc...
end

# And now, all you need to do inside the blocks is to convert the variables into 
# a symbol and pass in to haml to get that template.
```

Comment: Aha, thank you! It took me a minute to grok but I think I understand what's going on there now. Badass.

Comment: Since that is an array, you need to specify the index like so: `params[:splat][0]` which outputs 'foo' (String) and then that can be converted to a symbol. I've made an error in the second example. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the excellent answer by Kashyap.

If you want to name your parameters and not having to get them out of the `params` hash you can:

```
get '/*/test/*/notest' do |first, second|
  # assuming you accessed the address localhost/foo/test/bar/notest
  # first => 'foo'
  # second => 'bar'
  haml first.to_sym # etc etc
end
```